# Prisma 1:1 relation with no optional field on MySQL?

Tags: prisma

I was looking Prisma's documentation for 1:1 relation and i saw this piece of code:

```
  id      Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  profile Profile?
}

model Profile {
  id     Int  @id @default(autoincrement())
  user   User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId Int  @unique // relation scalar field (used in the `@relation` attribute above)
}
```

and it says that a user can have 0 or 1 profiles. But what if I want ensure that a user must have a profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer should be declared false, because the "?" is mandatoy see this [section](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/one-to-one-relations#required-and-optional-1-1-relation-fields).

Answer (score 1):

You can choose if the side of the relation with a relation scalar should be optional or mandatory. In the following example, profile and profileId are required. This means that you cannot create a User without connecting or making a Profile

```js
model User {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  profile   Profile @relation(fields: [profileId], references: [id]) // references `id` of `Profile`
  profileId Int     @unique // relation scalar field (used in the `@relation` attribute above)
}

model Profile {
  id   Int   @id @default(autoincrement())
  user User
}
```

See this [section](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/one-to-one-relations#required-and-optional-1-1-relation-fields) of the docs for required and optional 1-1 relation.

Comment: But that "?" means that I can create a profile without a user right? Is there a way to not allow the creation of a user without a profile and a profile without a user?

Comment: In that case you will omit the ? in User relation